# how to flatten a nested array using recursion in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion, nested, flatten

I am trying to flatten a nested array contained in array variable. Everything looks fine in the code but still not working. Please help me what's wrong with my code. According to me this code should return a flatten array like [1,2,3,4].

```
var array = [1,[2],[3,[[4]]]];

function flatten(array){

        return array.map(function(currentElement){

            if(Array.isArray(currentElement)){
                return flatten(currentElement);
            }else{
                return currentElement;
            }
        });
}

console.log(flatten(array)); // [1,[2],[3,[[4]]]]

// expected result => [1,2,3,4]
```

Comment: what about calling simply array.toString()

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/8ved8xwt/

Answer (score 1):

Just use `toString()`

```js
var array = [1,[2],[3,[[4]]]];
array = array.toString();
array = array.split(',');
console.log(array);
```

Comment: nice solution... :)

Comment: @AnkurShah welcome

Comment: But I need to flatten this array using Recursion. is my code wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combo of [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and [concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) for this purpose, since [flat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) is not implemented yet in the majority of the browsers.

```
const flatten = array => 
  array.reduce((r, v) => r.concat(Array.isArray(v) ? flatten(v) : v), []);


console.log(flatten([1,[2],[3,[[4]]]])) // [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: thanks a lot. it was helpful.

Comment: but still could not find why my code is not working.

Comment: Because you don't use `concat`, that's the key method. And, you're using `map`, so you can't really flatten with `map` since it returns always an array (of array, in your case).